# how to draw diamond using tapestry component t:loop

Tags: java, algorithm, math, tapestry

For my homework for Tapestry, I have to show a diamond on table from array of strings. Here's what I have so far:

code Index.java

```
  public class Index
    {
        @Property
        private Integer number;

        @Property
        private String [] table; 

        public Index() {
            number = 9;
            int temp = 0;

            String tmp = "-";
            table = new String[number * number];

            if(singleCell == null)
                singleCell="";

            for (int i = 0; i <  number; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <  number; j++) {
                    table[temp] = tmp;
                    temp++;
                }               
            }
        }

        @OnEvent(component="diamond")
        Object onDiamondLink() {
            String swapValue = "*";

            int  sum = number / 2 ;

            int x1 = number-1;

            int sumY = number / 2;

            int y1 = number+1;

            int temp = x1 + sumY;

            for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                table[i] = "-";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                if( i == sum) {
                    table[i] = swapValue;
                    sum = sum + x1;
                }
                if ( i == sumY ) {
                    table[i] = swapValue;
                    sumY = sumY + y1;
                } 
            }   

            System.out.println("link diamond is activate");
            return null;
        }
 public boolean isStartRow(){
         return (myIndex%9 ==0);
     }

     public boolean isEndRow(){
         return (myIndex%9 == 8);
     }

     public String getStartTR(){
         return "<tr >";
     }

     public String getEndTR(){
         return "</tr>";
    }
```

code of index.tml:

```
<t:actionlink t:id="diamond" >Diamond  table</t:actionlink>
            <br/>



         <h1>Result:</h1>

        <table border="1" >
            <t:loop t:source="table" t:value="singleCell" index="MyIndex">
                <t:if test="startRow">
                 <t:outputraw  value="startTR"/>
                </t:if>
                <td width="20px">
                    ${singleCell}
                </td>
            <t:if test="endRow">
                   <t:outputraw value="endTR"/>
           </t:if> 
            </t:loop>
        </table>
```

This code generates this output:

```
-   -   -   -   *   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   *   -   *   -   -   -
-   -   *   -   -   -   *   -   -
-   *   -   -   -   -   -   *   -
*   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   *
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   *   -
*   -   -   -   -   -   *   -   -
-   *   -   -   -   *   -   -   -
-   -   *   -   *   -   -   -   -
```

The correct output I need is this:

```
-   -   -   -   *   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   *   -   *   -   -   -
-   -   *   -   -   -   *   -   -
-   *   -   -   -   -   -   *   -
*   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   *
-   *   -   -   -   -   -   *   -
-   -   *   -   -   -   *   -   -
-   -   -   *   -   *   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   *   -   -   -   -
```

Any ideas will be great help.

Comment: You've almost nailed it,
The only thing that you've missed is the RowCount - ColCount == number /2 part, refer my answer below. It should be clear to you there.

Comment: I'm rather disappointed in the two answers. Not because of the content, but because of the principle.. the question clearly says "this is for my homework" and you guys just gave the code without any kind of explanation. People aren't going to learn by copy/pasting your code.

Comment: @Mannimarco I made an update, he can try ussing the outputraw component to try to display as html. Fore info can be found in google or at tapestry.org

Comment: could you please refactor my code. where is my mistake??i don't understand you??

Comment: Just curious, what school are you at that has you using Tapestry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanna draw a diamond? Try this algorithm:

```
public class Diamond {

    @Property
    @Persist
    private String diamond;


    @SetupRender    
    init(){
         int n,i,j,k;

     do {  

      n = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 3); 

      }while(n % 2 == 0);

      diamond += ""+n+"<br\/>";

      System.out.println();   

     for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){

        for (k = n; k > i; k--)
          diamond += "-";

        for (j =1; j <= i; j++)
             diamond += "*"+"-";


       diamond += "<br\/>";

        }

     for (i = n; i > 0; i--){

        for (k = n; k > i; k--)
          diamond += "-";

        for (j =1; j <= i; j++)
               diamond += "*"+"-";

              diamond += "<br\/>";

        }
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Wait a second, you want to create A tapestry page, that draws that diamond of asterisk right?

One option would be using:

```
<t:outputraw value="${diamond}"/>
```

You just need to set that String the .java part of your page.(See the above code was updated)

Your output need to be rendered as html, you can just use the algorithms we gave you and insert html breaks instead of println()

Comment: hi thanks for help. i have to use loop and table component in tml...not outputdraw component

Answer (score 0):

This should print the required output :

```
public class Diamond
{
  public static void main( String []args)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){ 
      for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
        if( (i + j == 4 ) || (i-j == 4)||(i+j == 12) || (j-i == 4))
          System.out.print("*");
        else
          System.out.print("-");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```